# Angular is not respecting browser field in package.json

Tags: angular

Repro steps:

1. `npm install @angular/cli`
2. `npx ng new my-app` (press enter for defaults to prompts)
3. `cd my-app`
4. `npx ng build` (notice that it works)
5. `npm install --save ethers`
6. Add `import { BigNumber } from 'ethers/utils'` to `my-app/src/app/app.component.ts`
7. Add `foo = new BigNumber(0)` to the `AppComponent` class in `my-app/src/app/app.component.ts`
8. `npx ng build` (notice that it fails)

The problem here is that the `ethers` library has a `package.json` with:

```
{
    "main": "./index.js",
    "browser": "./dist/ethers.min.js",
}
```

According to the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields), webpack should be using `./dist/ethers.min.js`.  However, from the errors we can see that it is trying to use `./index.js`, based on the fact that it is trying to read files that are part of the NodeJS build, rather than the browser build (which lives entirely in `dist` subdirectory).

Why isn't Angular respecting the `browser` field in `package.json`?  What do I need to do in order to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was doing imports in the form `import { BigNumber } from 'ethers/utils'`.  This style of import bypasses the `main` or `browser` properties on the `package.json`, which means that I was pulling in the node version no matter what was in there.

The solution, never use `import { ... } from '.../<something>'` when you are importing from a mixed target dependency.

Comment: `import { ... } from 'package-name'` or `import { ... } from './relative/path'`.  `package-name/sub-path` is a node-specific thing that doesn't work in browser (generally).